# Hooks in reactjs for getting data from firestore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

How do you get data from firestore using reactjs hooks?

I am working on an app where firestore is used as a database, so I have to fetch inserted data on an insert query using hooks in reactjs.
How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [this article on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a code writing service. Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on useEffect() hook. This hook is used for making asynchronous calls. So, you have to put the fetch inside this hook.